# how to create two table with custom primary and Foreign key

Tags: python, django

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    userame=models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text='Enter user name that you want', unique=True, primary_key=True) **#want have userame as primary key**
    mobile_number=models.IntegerField()
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Fist_Name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Last_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Order(models.Model):
    username=models.OneToOneField(UserInfo,on_delete=models.CASCADE) **#user name of UserInfo table want to be foreign key in Order table**
    Prodduc_name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

It's failing with django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1829, "Cannot drop column 'id': needed in a foreign key constraint 'woodshophome_passwor_username_id_35d147b1_fk_woodshoph' of table 'woodshophome_passwordtable'")
woodshophoe is app name

Comment: Can't understand your question. You can use `models.ForeignKey` to add ForeignKey to other tables.

Comment: [Docs link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) here.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved, i want to OneToOne relastionship between two table(UserInfo and Order). In which username from UserInfo table need to be foreign key in Order table. By defaulg django maintains it by id column